# Multiple mysql servers with one database?

Tags: mysql, sql

What are the options for having multiple mysql servers with the same database and data. I know there is replication but I have been reading that it can have issues especially if there are connection issues. Are there any alternatives to the built in replication that are reliable? Someone suggested getting a server on the same network so the mysql server can be accessed by all the servers over lan, but currently that is not an option for me.

Is mysql just not meant for replication? Is there another sql engine that is better for it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few options for replicating a MySQL database. Here are a few no-cost options:

- MySQL 5.5 has a new semi-synchronous feature that increases the reliability
- MySQL Cluster - community edition is no cost
- [Tungsten Replicator](http://www.continuent.com/solutions/tungsten-replicator)
- [DRBD and Linux HA](http://www.drbd.org)

Tungsten and Linux HA both provide failover so that the master database will automatically move to another machine if the primary master fails. However, with DRBD, the second machine is typically passive, meaning that it doesn't serve any traffic at all, while with native MySQL or Tungsten you can use the slaves for reading data.

Comment: If the slave only needs to be able to read from a single table what would you recommend?

Comment: In order to make a choice a lot more detail is needed around your infrastructure and what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I have a vbulletin forum and want to be able to use the user information from a remote server for a WCF service. I guess I could add an api to vbulletin to request information but the issue is that the forum server goes down a lot and I would like the program that uses the user table to not go down when the forum goes down.

Comment: In that case, default mysql replication would be fine. You can even specify the slave server to only replicate a single server

Answer (score 1):

The obvious answer would be [MySQL Cluster Manager](http://www.mysql.com/products/cluster/mcm/), it costs though.

Comment: Do I need MySQL Cluster Manager for this or can I just manually configure MySQL Cluster?